# Except python не ловит ошибку виндовс FileNotFoundError | "Системе не удается найти указанный путь."

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, исключения, windows-10

Дело в том что я хочу сделать так что-бы если папки нет то она сама создавалась.
но except вообще не ловит эту ошибку ни в какую ни с "Windows Error" ни c "OS Error"  ни просто без указания, а в интерпретаторе питона в коммандной строке вместо ошибки 'File Not Found Error" пишет таже самая ошибка виндовс: "Системе не удается найти указанный путь.

```
try:    
    config_file = f"C:/Windows/testdir"
    os.system(f"cd {config_file}")
    print(config_file)
    # pass

except:
    print("Config File not Found!\nConfig File created...")
```

Вывод:

> C:/Windows/testdir

> Системе не удается найти указанный путь.

Пожалуйста помогите если можете

Comment: Это для питона отлично выполненная команда, а не исключение. Проверяйте файловыми функциями путь

Comment: Исключения нет. Вы видите вывод, который генерирует подпроцесс, созданный вызовом `os.system`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.path.exists` проверяет наличие папки по данному пути. Если папка была найдена, выводится путь и надпись "Config file has found!". Если нет, выводится "Config file not found! Config file created...".  После этого `os.mkdir` создаёт папку по указанному пути и выводит "Config file created successfully!", что означает, что папка успешно создана.

```
import os
config_file = "C:/Windows/testdir"
if os.path.exists(config_file): # проверяет наличие файла/папки
    print(f"{config_file}\nConfig file has found!")
else:
    print("Config File not Found!\nCreate config file...")
    os.mkdir("C:/Windows/testdir") # создаёт файл/папку по указанной директории
    print("Config file created successfully!")
```

Может, у **alex** будет более понятно, я объяснил как мог.

**alex**, путь к файлам не зависит от того, какой слэш стоит, что `C:/Windows/testdir`, что `C:\Windows\testdir`, оба перенаправляют туда, куда надо.

Comment: **Nice1ce**, спасибо ! Переписал так: ```import os

config_file = 'C:/User/os/testdir2'
os.mkdir( config_file )
os.chdir( config_file )
```

Comment: Спасибо Большое! Я изменил код и все заработало! Теперь выводится ошибка если папки нет, и открывается фал если она есть. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Вы очень понятно объяснили, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**IMPoRT-**, в системе Windows папки адресуются не прямым слэшем, а обратным

Т.е. вместо `C:/Windows/testdir` надо написать `C:\Windows\testdir`

Далее, когда мы переворачиваем слэш, т.е. пишем `\` в питоне начинают отрабатывать специальные управляющие символы, например, `\t` это табуляция, поэтому C:\Windows **\t**estdir работать не будет. Чтобы отключить в строке питона табуляцию, вам надо вместо буквы `f` в начале строки написать букву `r`, т.е. `r"C:\Windows\testdir"`

Когда я всё это написал у себя в коде, мне система Windows сказала, что вы не имеете доступа в папку Windows, что логично. Давайте изменим путь на такой

```
import os

config_file = r'C:\Users\ВашеИмя\testdir'
os.system( f'mkdir {config_file}' )
os.system( f'cd {config_file}' )

'''
IMPoRT-
'''
```

При повторном запуске из папки ничего не удаляется, а просто выводится сообщение о том, что папка наша уже существует. Поэтому в вашем примере можно обойтись без исключений ( exceptions ).

Comment: Спасибо, но я это знаю, ошибка не вылавливалась в любом случае, в том то и проблема.

Comment: Но проблемы к счастью больше нет)

Comment: @IMPoRT-, понятно. Я сам не знал, как её решить, хорошо, что **Nice1ce** нам помог :)

Comment: Да, так и есть, спасибо ему)